# Suspend and shutdown not working on HP Zbook Studio G9 Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: suspend, shutdown

Since beginning of august 2023, after an update of my ubuntu (apt upgrade), the suspend mode doesn't work anymore, it goes to suspend but cannot resume from it (still black screen).
Same for the shutdown, if I shutdown, the system hangs forever and I need to hard shutdown it (10s on power on button).
Does anyone has any idea what could be the issue ?

Here are the detail of my system
HW Model: HP HP ZBook Studio 16 inch G9 Mobile Workstation PC
Processor: 12th Gen Intel® Core™ i7-12800H × 20
Graphics: Mesa Intel® Graphics (ADL GT2)
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS 64bits
GNOME version: 42.9
Windows System: x11

Comment: same here... I can login on my laptop only using a previous kernel (5.X).
I'm wondering whether a BIOS update could be helpful. I'll give a try when I have time

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when i got my new ZBook from HP, it's super annoying, cause you don't find any useful information about the issue in Google, but after a while of debugging what exactly the issue is i found it.

Just gotta deactivate in the BIOS the HP Energy Safe controll stuff, the bios wants to control the "suspend" state which doesn't work with ubuntu or any Linux distro tbh.

Rather take a Lenovo if you got the choice and want to use other than Windoof